# Accessing values with different types in object map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, typescript, javascript-objects

I have some data which looks like this -

```
    {
      System: 'VIT0056',
      Value: {
        Start: 3.3,
        End: 3.9
      },
      'Initial Range' : {
        'Start': '1/12/2022',
        'End': '31/12/2022',
      },
      Manager: 'Karl Woods',
      Location: 'Tokyo',
      Price: '$1.50',
    },
```

I am currently mapping over this object like so -

```
 {Object.entries(data).map(([key, val]) => {
              if (key === 'Value') {
                return (
                  <S.ValueContainer key={key}>
                    <Label>{key}:</Label>
                    <Text size="small">** DO SOMETHING HERE TO SHOW VALUES **</Text>
                  </S.ValueContainer>
                )
              }

              if (key === 'Initial Range') {
                return (
                  <S.ValueContainer key={key}>
                    <Label>{key}:</Label>
                    <Text size="small">** DO SOMETHING HERE TO SHOW VALUES ** </Text>
                  </S.ValueContainer>
                )
              }

              return (
                <S.ValueContainer key={key}>
                  <Label>{key}:</Label>
                  <Text size="small">{val}</Text>
                </S.ValueContainer>
              )
            }
         )
      }
```

For the Value and Initial Range keys I want to be able to show them like this -

Value : 3.3 - 3.9

Initial Range: From 01 Dec 2022 To 31 Dec 2022

However I am having trouble accessing the values due to the fact that they are nested objects.

When I put them inside the if statement and try to do `val.Start` it tells me that -

Property 'Start' does not exist on type 'string | Range'.

But I know that the value I'll be accessing in this block will only be of type Range. Is there a way to define this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell your compiler, that the value actually is a `Range`

```
<Text size="small">{(val as Range).Start} - {(val as Range).End}</Text>
```

or you can implement a `ToString(value: string | Range)` function

```
function ToString(value: string | Range) {
  //if value is a string, just return the value
  if (typeof value === "string") return value;

  //here the compiler knows it must be a Range
  //because it's not a string ...
  return `${value.Start} - ${value.End}`;
}
```

and use this in your rendering

```
<Text size="small">{ToString(val)}</Text>
```

Furthermore, you seem to have different types of ranges also. So when using the `ToString()` approach, you might also need to do a typecheck on your start and end properties

```
function ToString(value: string | Range) {
  if (typeof value === "string") return value;

  if (typeof value.Start === "number")
    return `${value.Start} - ${value.End}`;

 //here you know value is a range and
 //the properties of range are strings
 //(given both always have the same type

  //or apply appropriate formatting for your dates
  return `${value.Start} to ${value.End}`;

}
```

Of course you can also return some renderings instead of only strings. As in the following example

```
function ToRender(value: string | Range) {
  //if value is a string, just return the value
  if (typeof value === "string") return (<div>{value}</div>);

  //here the compiler knows it must be a Range
  //because it's not a string ...
  return (<div><span>{value.Start}</span> to <span>{value.End}</span></div>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass your object into `Object.entries`, you are essentially decoupling your keys from the types of their associated values. It looks like the array you are iterating over has type `[string, string | Range][]`, presumably with `Range` being some custom type defined elsewhere.

If you want to access properties on your object in a way where the association between keys and value types is maintained, then you should access them through the object instead of using the `val` argument accessible within your map callback.

So instead of `val.Start`, try `data[key].Start` (once you've narrowed the type of `key` of course).

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a common issue with union types, the reason the error exists is to stop you from trying to access `Start` when the you have a `string` for `val`.

I would check the type first, like so:

```js
      {Object.entries(data).map(([key, val]) => {
        if (typeof val !== "string") {
          if (key === "Value") {
            return (
              <S.ValueContainer key={key}>
                <Label>{key}:</Label>
                <Text size="small">** DO SOMETHING HERE TO SHOW VALUES **</Text>
              </S.ValueContainer>
            );
          }

          if (key === "Initial Range") {
            return (
              <S.ValueContainer key={key}>
                <Label>{key}:</Label>
                <Text size="small">** DO SOMETHING HERE TO SHOW VALUES ** </Text>
              </S.ValueContainer>
            );
          }
        }

        return (
          <S.ValueContainer key={key}>
            <Label>{key}:</Label>
            <Text size="small">{val}</Text>
          </S.ValueContainer>
        );
      })}
```

This would then always fall back to just showing the value of `val` and then for the other parts you are free to access `Start` and `End` on the `Range` type.